# How can I tell that a NetTcp-based WCF connection was interrupted?

Tags: wcf, nettcpbinding

A WCF service is based on NetTcpBinding. It may happen that a client silently vanishes, leaving the server without knowledge that it is not connected anymore.

I'm currently using a thread that pings all connected client to see if they are still alive, and removes disconnected clients.

- Is a ping thread the correct way to solve the issue, or is there a better, possibly event-based way?
- Do I have to surround every code that communicates with the client by try/catch and remove it from the list of connected clients additionally?

Comment: what to you mean by "the server thinking that it is still connected"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe I found the answer myself.

There is an event `OperationContext.Current.Channel.Closing` that is fired on faulted as well as closed connections.

Comment: Since nobody brought up a different answer, I'm going to agree with myself.